# RavenDB: How do you use the dump file created by Smuggler?

Tags: ravendb

Ayende tells people upfront: [RavenDB is awful at reporting.](http://ayende.com/blog/136197/when-should-you-not-use-ravendb)

To compensate for the shortcoming, RavenDB has a tool called Smuggler which can export your RavenDB data to an RDBMS.

My Question:

- How do you use the dump file created by Smuggler?

Emphasis: The RavenDB documentation [explains how to generate a dump file](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/export-import), but it doesn't explain what to do next.

When I generate the dump file and open it with notepad, it contains lots of symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use Smuggler for this.  Smuggler is for backup/restore to Raven.  You should use SQL Replication instead.

The docs for this on www.ravendb.net are currently reflecting the *old* index replication bundle.  There is a new and better way that is not yet fully documented.  For details, see [this blog post by Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/160641/ravendb-2-1-features-robust-sql-replication), and watch [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlpawSkHD4U).

Also - Raven is ok at generating data for reports - it is just not good at *ad hoc* reporting.  You must pre-generate all of your data.  This is acceptable in many situations.

There's also [a really good feature](http://ayende.com/blog/161249/ravendbs-querying-streaming-unbounded-results) in RavenDB 2.5 that helps stream all data in a consistant manner.  This is perfect for reporting purposes.

Really, the best reason to replicate to SQL is if you want your end-users to have raw access to the data.  For example - if they want to attach to a datasource from an Excel spreadsheet and create their own PivotTables - then you can't do that without first replicating to a SQL server.

Comment: How relevant is this today in 2022? Are there other options now for migrating data out of RavenDB?

Comment: No idea, sorry.  This answer was relevant in 2013, but I haven't used RavenDB in a long time.